# How do I get double sided printing working on a HP Laserjet 2300DN with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, hp-laserjet

I have a HP LaserJet 2300DN connected var the network (TCP direct to printer), however when I set it up on Windows 7 (64 bit) the driver does not give me the option to do double sided printing.

How do I get the driver to know I am using the "DN" rather than a basic 2300?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the tool on this page:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=238811&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=238800&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063

to check if you have the correct drivers and if not download the latest Win 7 64bit drivers.

You could also try connecting the printer to the computer direct if possible to see if its an issue with Win 7 or your network and come back here with more information.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't vote nor comment up there. I just want to say that the answer from Jade Robbins worked well for me. It was on Device Setting.

1- Go to: Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers
2- Right click on your printer icon and select 'Printer Properties'
3- Go to Device Settings Properties
4- Under 'Installable Options' choose: Installed for 'Duplex Unit (for 2-Sided Printing)'

Mohammad

Comment: The additional details you added justify an answer rather then a comment.   Some screen dump marked up with were to click would be the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the printer properties (under "Device Settings") you let the system know that it has a duplexer unit installed.